# Calendar in c with sum of last row

Tags: c, arrays, calendar, sum

I'm trying to make a one-month calendar that prints the sum of the last row of days.

The output of this is correct for the calendar, but the sum keeps printing out that it's 0.  For an input of 3=day_of_week and 30=days_in_month, the sum should be 26+27+28+29+30 = 140

Thanks.

```
int main() {

int day_of_week, days_in_month, i, row=1, array[31], sum=0, a;

printf("Enter the day of the week 1=sun, 2=mon, 3=tue, 4=wed, 5=thurs, 6=fri, 7=sat\n");
scanf("%d", &day_of_week);

printf("Enter the number of days in this month:\n");
scanf("%d", &days_in_month);

for (i=0; i<3*day_of_week; i++)
    printf(" ");

for (i=1; i<=days_in_month; i++) {

    printf("%3d", i);
    array[i] = i;

    day_of_week++;

    if (day_of_week%7==0){
        printf("\n");
    }

}
    printf("\n");
    for (a=days_in_month; a>=(days_in_month-(7-day_of_week)); a--)
        sum+=array[a];

printf("sum of last row is %d\n", sum);


return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you are doing **++day_of_week**,

something like this should work better:

```
int main()
{
    int day_of_week, days_in_month, i, row=1, array[31], sum=0, a;

    printf("Enter the day of the week 1=sun, 2=mon, 3=tue, 4=wed, 5=thurs, 6=fri,     7=sat\n");
    scanf("%d", &day_of_week);

    printf("Enter the number of days in this month:\n");
    scanf("%d", &days_in_month);

    for (i = 0; i < 3 * day_of_week; i++)
        printf(" ");
    for (i = 1; i <= days_in_month; i++)
    {
        printf("%3d", i);
        array[i] = i;
        if (i % 7 == 0)
            printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (a=days_in_month; a>=(days_in_month-(7-day_of_week)); a--)
        sum+=array[a];
    printf("sum of last row is %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't print out the calendar correctly, and the sum is still 0

Comment: Actually, my mistake, the sum prints out correctly but the calendar is messed up.

Comment: Just try to review your entire code and know what you want to have in result, then you'll find out what to do !

Comment: Just had to make it:
if ((i+day_of_week)%7 == 0)
    printf("\n");

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
for (a=days_in_month; a>=(days_in_month-(7-day_of_week)); a--)
```

but `day_of_week` does not remain constant in your program and changes before with this statement:

`day_of_week++;`

Use a second variable to increment and do not modify `day_of_week` after `scanf`.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is here:

```
for (i=1; i<=days_in_month; i++) {

    printf("%3d", i);
    array[i] = i;

    day_of_week++;

    if (day_of_week%7==0){
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

You are allowing `day_of_week` to go out of range.  Your code expects that value to be no more than 7.  This loop will result in that variable being set to the value the user entered plus (`days_in_month` - 1).  In your final `for` loop, the statement `7 - day_of_week` will likely be negative, which will throw the rest of your code off.

You are sort of checking for overflow when you test the variable modulo 7 and print a newline.  When you do that, set `day_of_week = 0` as well.

Also, calculate `(days_in_month-(7-day_of_week))` and store it in a temporary variable as soon as you get the input from the user.  Since you're manipulating these variables inside your code, your final `for` loop probably isn't using the values that you think it's using.  Alternatively, don't modify the variables that you use for user input and create other variables to use as temporaries.